# matplotlib set stacked bar chart labels

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart that groups data by operating system. I'm having trouble creating an individual label for each component in each bar.

What I'm trying to do is different from the [example in the docs](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html) because in my data each category appears in only one bar, whereas in the example each bar contains one member of each category.

Currently I have this code

```
plt.cla()
plt.clf()
plt.close()

def get_cmap(n, name='hsv'):
    '''Returns a function that maps each index in 0, 1, ..., n-1 to a distinct 
    RGB color; the keyword argument name must be a standard mpl colormap name.'''
    return plt.cm.get_cmap(name, n)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 10), dpi=80)

# group by the prefixes for now
prefixes = []
indices = []
bars = []
legend = {}
cmap = get_cmap(len(os_counts.index) + 1)
k = 0
for i, prefix in enumerate(d):
    indices.append(i)
    if len(d[prefix]["names"]) == 1:
        prefixes.append(d[prefix]["names"][0])
    else:
        prefixes.append(prefix)
    #colors = [next(cycol) for j in range(len(d[prefix]["names"]))]
    colors = [cmap(k + j) for j in range(len(d[prefix]["names"]))]
    k += len(colors)
    bar = plt.bar([i] * len(d[prefix]["names"]), d[prefix]["values"], color=colors, label=d[prefix]["names"])
    bars.append(bar)


plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.xlabel("Operating System")
plt.xticks(indices, prefixes)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Which produces this result. As you can see, the legend is created for the first colour within the bar and shows an array.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that each call to plt.bar gets one label. So, you are giving it a list as a label for each plt.bar call. If you want a label for every color, representing every operating system then I think the solution is to call plt.bar once for each color or os.